# Does this from a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

All vectors of the form :

$\left(a-2b,a+b,3a\right)$

Where $a,b$ are any real numbers.

I understand that for it to form a vector space it has to satisfy vector addition and scalar multiplication. But here it appears not too.

However when I think about what it might look like graphically it forms a straight line through $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.

So my question is does this form a vector space and does a line through $\mathbb{R}$ form a vector space ?

Comment: Why do you think it fails to satisfy the addition and multiplication axioms?

Comment: Also;  there is no $c$ in your expression.  Was there supposed to be?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but is it because if we multiplied it by some constant it would not be apart of the vector space ?

Comment: $\lambda\times(a-2b,a+b,3a)=(\lambda a-2\lambda b,\lambda a +\lambda b,3\lambda a)$.  So just replace the data $(a,b)$ with $(\lambda a, \lambda b)$.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: So it does not form a vector space ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All vectors of the form :
>
> $\left(a-2b,a+b,3a\right)$
>
> Where $a,b$ are any real numbers.

You can interpret this as the result of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 \\
1 & 1 \\
3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b
\end{pmatrix} 
\iff
y = A x
$$
thus the image of $\mathbb{R}^2$ via $A$. This $A$ is a linear map, and thus we get a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

> However when I think about what it might look like graphically it
>   forms a straight line through $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.

No, it is two dimensional, a plane.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & -2 & y_1 \\
1 & 1  & y_2 \\
3 & 0  & y_3
\end{array}
\right)
\to
\left(
\begin{array}{rr|r}
0 & -2 & y_1 - (1/3) y_3 \\
0 & 1  & y_2 - (1/3) y_3 \\
1 & 0  & (1/3) y_3
\end{array}
\right)
\to
\left(
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & 0  & (1/3) y_3 \\
0 & 1  & y_2 - (1/3) y_3 \\
0 & 0  & y_1 + 2 y_2 - y_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
This gives $(a, b) = ((1/3) y_3, y_2 - (1/3)y_3)$ and the constraint 
$$
0 = (y1 + 2 y_2 - y_3) = (1, 2, -1) \cdot (y_1, y_2, y_3) = n \cdot y
$$
which is a normal equation of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with normal vector $n$.

[image: resulting plane]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48YXR.png))

> So my question is does this form a vector space and does a line
>   through $\mathbb{R}$ form a vector space ?

Yes and yes, if that line includes the origin.

Comment: What would indicate to you that it is a plane as opposed to a line ?

Comment: I extended the answer to make this clear.